# npx expo start SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 223

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to install the expo-cli with wsl2 and also tired with windows terminal but each time its throughing the JSON error which seems to be impossible to track

/> i  tried downgrading the nodejs
/> use expo-cli newer version npx expo-cli (following the official documentation)
/> cleared cache

i feels like we are stucked!

resistor@AR:/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp$ npx expo start
Starting project at /mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp
SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 223
SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 223
at JSON.parse ()
at readPackageJSON (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/find-yarn-workspace-root/index.js:50:17)
at findWorkspaceRoot (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/find-yarn-workspace-root/index.js:23:22)
at getWorkspaceRoot (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/getModulesPaths.js:26:49)
at getWatchFolders (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/getWatchFolders.js:112:65)
at getDefaultConfig (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:172:63)
at Object.loadAsync (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:272:23)
at Object.instantiateMetroAsync (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/instantiateMetro.js:41:45)
at MetroBundlerDevServer.startImplementationAsync (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.js:48:87)
at async MetroBundlerDevServer.startAsync (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/BundlerDevServer.js:89:24)
at async DevServerManager.startAsync (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/DevServerManager.js:136:13)
at async startAsync (/mnt/e/wk/mern/project1/client/mobo1/myapp/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/startAsync.js:115:5)

/> i  tried downgrading the nodejs
/> use expo-cli newer version npx expo-cli (following the official documentation)
/> cleared cache